# Firebase : firebase.Promise<any> compatibility with Rxjs Promise<any>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to convert a `firebase.Promise` into an `Observable` using a project generated by angular-cli.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise) it's said that `firebase.Promise` are compatible with `Native Promise` and `Promise/A+` implementation.

However I get an error when I try to use the `Observable.fromPromise()` method of rxjs.

```
Argument of type 'firebase.Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any>'.                                                               
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.                                                                                                                  
    Type '(onResolve?: (a: any) => any, onReject?: (a: Error) => any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '{ <TResult1, TResult2>(onfulfilled: (value: 
any) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected:...'.                                                                                                    
      Type 'firebase.Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
```

It actually work but having error is annoying, any idea about how to avoid this error in a clean way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: Yep I am using TS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TypeScript you can use type casting:

```
let promise = firebase.whatever();
Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>promise);
```